# [UR3] Connection setup failed! ur_modern_driver

Tags: ros, driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having some trouble trying to use UR3 with ROS-Kinetic.
I was hopping I can get a little help.

I followed the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver).

My software setup is as follows:

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Native Machine)
- ROS Kinetic
- UR_Software and Polyscope 3.4.0
- ur_modern_driver on the kinetic-devel branch

For the hardware side, I followed this instructions. [here](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial)

I am directly connecting the UR3 to my Linux PC through a Ethernet port located in the bottom of the UR3 control box.

I have enabled the network and set it up as static address as follows:

- ip address 192.168.0.254
- net mask 255.255.255.0
- gateway 192.168.0.2

In my Linux PC I added a new profile for the UR3 connection, I set the method to manual and used the information posted above.

I than pinged the ip and I got a response.

ping 192.168.0.254

In the UR3 controller, the network had a "connected to network" message so I assumed I did this step correctly.

I than continued the instructions and ran:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-ur-description

roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur3_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.254
```

This is where I am receiving the error message I put in the title of this ticket.

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [3706]
process[ur_driver-2]: started with pid [3707]
[ INFO] [1559898682.404748254]: Setting up connection: 192.168.0.254:30003
[ERROR] [1559898682.404906903]: Connection setup failed for 192.168.0.254:30003
[ INFO] [1559898682.404926848]: Setting up connection: 192.168.0.254:30001
[ERROR] [1559898682.405033532]: Connection setup failed for 192.168.0.254:30001
[ WARN] [1559898682.405060387]: Failed to read from stream, reconnecting in 1 seconds...
```

I was hopping I could get some assistance.
I know I am doing something wrong but I do not know what it is.

Any tips or help will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324950/%5Bur3%5D-connection-setup-failed!-ur_modern_driver/) by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-07**:
First thing to check: is `192.168.0.254` the IP of the robot or the IP of your own PC?

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-09**:
That is the IP I set for the robot in its teach pendant.
I set it as static.

Am I supposed to set my PC's IP address?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:\

> Am I supposed to set my PC's IP address?

no, and I also don't believe I implied that. The `.launch` `arg`'s name is even `robot_ip`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:
What is the output of:

```
nc 192.168.0.254 30003 > /dev/null
```

or

```
nc 192.168.0.254 30002 > /dev/null
```

also:

> I than pinged the ip and I got a response.

can you show that response?

Please *edit* your original question using the `edit` link/button. Do not post comments with console output.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
Hi gvdhoorn, thank you for your reply.
I have found out the cause of the error message I had posted.

It was a simple and dumb mistake on my part. I will give more detail in the answer I will post following this comment. I apologize if I wasted your time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:\

> I apologize if I wasted your time.

no need to apologise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When setting up the 1 to 1 connection from the UR3 to the PC, I made the mistake of setting both of them to the same IP address.

Since both devices had the same IP address, I would get the error message mentioned above.

Changing the IP address of my PC to `192.168.0.253` solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:
So can you explain how you were able to `ping 192.168.0.254` before?

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
Sure, created a new network connection profile in my PC. I set the IP address manually and I used the IP address I set in my Robots teach pendant. After I did this I was able to connect to the robot. Using `ping 192.168.0.254` I received *64 bytes from 192.168.0.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms*

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
I tried using the command you mentioned `nc 192.168.0.254 30003 > /dev/null` but in the terminal nothing was being outputted. I checked the file generated in /dev/null and it mentioned that I could not open it in gedit as it was not a regular file. Did I make a mistake here?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:\

> Sure, created a new network connection profile in my PC. I set the IP address manually and I used the IP address I set in my Robots teach pendant.

So why would you need to use `sudo ifconfig` now then?

re: `nc`: it's not supposed to generate any output. Unless something is wrong. Then it will print an error.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:\

> So why would you need to use sudo ifconfig now then

When researching about this problem, I went through many tutorials like this [one](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ur/ur_setup/controller.html) to check if I was missing a step somewhere. In the tutorial it mentioned

> Select the IP Address entry box and put in an IP address. The first 3 sets of numbers should match the IP address you have on your computer

I understood it as my PC needed to have a different IP address then that of my robot but, it still needed to be under `192.168.1`.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
To be honest, I am not sure why this fixed my issue and I do not understand what the original issue was. All I understood that using `sudo ifconfig` fixed it. Should I change my answer?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:
`sudo ifconfig` should not be necessary. You should be able to configure your network configuration normally and not need to run a command line tool every time you start your computer (as that is going to be needed afaict).

If you can provide some more information on your network configuration (ie: how many network cards, if a single one: is it also used for internet access, etc), then perhaps we can provide you with a more convenient setup.

But do understand this has nothing to do with either ROS or the `ur_modern_driver`. It's basic networking.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
It is just a normal tower and the Ethernet cable is being directly connected to the motherboard as well as UR3's Ethernet port located in the bottom of the control box.

> But do understand this has nothing to do with either ROS or the ur_modern_driver. It's basic networking.

I think this is the case.
Before, I was not sure if it was an issue with `ur_modern_driver`, UR3 itself, or just an error on my part.
I tried reading the manuals as well as forums but I lack to much knowledge in all parts needed to use UR3 with ROS. I am sorry for troubling you.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:
I forgot to mention this but the PC (tower) has no internet access. It is directly being connected to the robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:
Please stop apologising. There is no need.

If this is a direct 1-to-1 connection with no need for internet connectivity over the same link, then just configure a static IP on your PC as well using the network manager in Ubuntu. There would be no need for `ifconfig`.

Make sure both the PC and the CB3 of the UR are in the same subnet (ie: "under `192.168.1`"). You already have a candidate IP (`192.168.1.253`), so you could use that. Set *Subnet Mask* to `255.255.255.0`. You can leave the gateway empty. Remove the gateway setting on the CB3.

If you want to lookup further information on networking, don't restrict yourself to the UR controller. As far as the network is concerned, it acts just like any other host on a TCP/IP network.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-10**:\

> then just configure a static IP on your PC as well using the network manager in Ubuntu.

Understood. Thank you very much. It seems the step I was missing was to set the Static IP of my PC.

> You can leave the gateway empty. Remove the gateway setting on the CB3.

I will make sure to do this.
I will also study up on networking.

Again thank you for your support.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
Could you please update your answer once/if you get everything to work without needing `ifconfig`?

Note: there is a legitimate use-case for `ifconfig`: if you want to keep your network connection on *automatic* but also need to add a static IP to the same connection. That is not the case here, hence my suggestion to not use `ifconfig`.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-11**:\

> Could you please update your answer once/if you get everything to work without needing ifconfig?

Sure. I updated it for now stating what the issue was and how I was able to solve it.
I have not yet updated to tell how exactly I did this though, as I am still learning about networking.

I will update the answer again once I have a step by step process on how I managed to do this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:\

> I will update the answer again once I have a step by step process on how I managed to do this.

This is not very difficult. See [HowtoForge/Setting a static IP on Ubuntu: a beginner's guide: Configuring IP address using the Desktop Application](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/howto-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu/#-configuring-ip-address-using-the-desktop-application) for one page showing you how to do this.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-11**:\

> This is not very difficult. See

I finally understood what I was doing wrong.
When setting the connection (Configuring IP address using the Desktop Application), I was using the Robot's IP address rather then setting up my PC's address.

I originally thought that if I wanted to connect to the robot, I needed to tell the PC which IP the robot was using.

So basically both the Robot and my PC had the same IP address hence why the Robot could not connect.

Hopefully my understanding is correct now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
Ok. This was actually exactly why I asked:

> First thing to check: is `192.168.0.254` the IP of the robot or the IP of your own PC?

in my first comment.

Good to hear you have solved it.

**Comment by [Robotics123z](https://answers.ros.org/users/42145/robotics123z/) on 2019-06-12**:
Yea
I did not understand your first comment at first but now I get it.

Thank you for all your help and support. I appreciate it.